# iText AddImage() to specific page

Tags: itext

I'm having a problem trying to locate a PdfContentByte directly into an specific page. My problem is: I need to add an Image for each page (That works) and need to add a QRCode to each of the pages at the right bottom corner but this works only for the first Page and I don't know how to repeat it on the other ones.

This is my code:

```
        public string GeneratePDFDocument(Atomic.Development.Montenegro.Data.Entities.Document document, Stamp stamp)
        {
            string filename = @"C:\Users\Sheldon\Desktop\Pdf.Pdf";
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);

            iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDocument = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER, PAGE_LEFT_MARGIN, PAGE_RIGHT_MARGIN, PAGE_TOP_MARGIN, PAGE_BOTTOM_MARGIN);
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, fs);

            pdfDocument.Open();

            int count = document.Pages.Count;
            foreach (Page page in document.Pages)
            {
                Image img = Image.GetInstance(page.Image);
                img.ScaleToFit(PageSize.LETTER.Width-(PAGE_LEFT_MARGIN + PAGE_RIGHT_MARGIN), PageSize.LETTER.Height-(PAGE_TOP_MARGIN + PAGE_BOTTOM_MARGIN));
                pdfDocument.Add(img);

                PlaceCodeBar(writer);

            }

            pdfDocument.Close();
            writer.Close();
            fs.Close();

            return filename;
        }

        private static void PlaceCodeBar(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer)
        {
            String codeText = "TEXT TO ENCODE";

            iTextSharp.text.pdf.BarcodePDF417 pdf417 = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.BarcodePDF417();
            pdf417.SetText(codeText);
            Image img = pdf417.GetImage();
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.BarcodeQRCode qrcode = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.BarcodeQRCode(codeText, 1, 1, null);
            img = qrcode.GetImage();


            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
            cb.SaveState();
            cb.BeginText();

            img.SetAbsolutePosition(PageSize.LETTER.Width-PAGE_RIGHT_MARGIN-img.ScaledWidth, PAGE_BOTTOM_MARGIN);
            cb.AddImage(img);
            cb.EndText();
            cb.RestoreState();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure out how to solve the problem. Just delete the cb.SaveState() and cb.RestoreState() and it put the image on the page is actually active.

Comment: That *shouldn't* help.  That it did worries me.  Something else is going on.

Answer (score 4):

So add it in your `foreach (Page...)` loop:

```
        foreach (Page page in document.Pages)
        {
            Image img = Image.GetInstance(page.Image);
            img.ScaleToFit(PageSize.LETTER.Width-(PAGE_LEFT_MARGIN + PAGE_RIGHT_MARGIN), PageSize.LETTER.Height-(PAGE_TOP_MARGIN + PAGE_BOTTOM_MARGIN));
            pdfDocument.Add(img);
            PlaceCodeBar(writer);
        }
```

If this is a second pass on the same PDF (you've closed it then opened it again), use a `PdfStamper` rather than a `PdfWriter`.  You can then get the direct content of each page rather than the one direct content that is reused (and reset) for each page.

PS: Drop the `BeginText()` and `EndText()` calls.  Those operators should only be used when actually drawing text/setting fonts/etc.  No line art.  No images.  The `SaveState()`/`RestoreState()` are good though.  Definitely keep those.

Comment: Thanks Mark, but actually I forgot to put it on the code but I was doing that and it prints the code only on the first page. I suppose maybe is related with the img.SetAbsolutePosition(..) of the PlaceCodeBar